# Ubuntu 11.04 wireless network problem

Tags: wireless

In my notebook, update my ubuntu to 11.04. After that my wireless network is down. Not work now! Have ubuntu a bug about network?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that Ubuntu does not have a glaring bug that prevents anyone from using a wireless network. I don't use the software, but I still know somehow that that would never get released. And there isn't anywhere *close* to enough information provided in your question to actually help you solve this problem.

Comment: We need to know what wireless chipset you use. Please update the your question with this info. You can find out by opening a terminal and doing: `lspci -v | less` and pressing space to page down.

Answer (score -2):

switch on your bluetooth and type sudo rfkill unblock wifi  in terminal and enter your login password.Now wireless the network will be detected.